# No Values in Getter and Setter Methods with Button in Template

Tags: java, html, jsf, jsf-2

i have a the template **AdvanceTemplate.xhtml**. And a **footer.xhtml**. This footer has the submit-Button. I have a **store.xhtml** page with with a inputText.
But when i cklick the submit button the data from my view-klass isn't save from the inputfield.
If i put the button in at the same xhtml (store.xhtml) page where im inputText is placed i get the data.

How must i write it to get the data from the inputText field, when i have the Button in the template?

**AdvanceTemplate.xhtml**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <head>
      <title><ui:insert name="title">Example</ui:insert></title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="header">
        <ui:insert name="header">
            <ui:include src="/META-INF/templates/header.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="information">
        <ui:insert name="information">
         <ui:include src="/META-INF/templates/information.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content">
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <ui:include src="/META-INF/templates/advanceFooter.xhtml"/>
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**advanceFooter.xhtml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head></h:head> 
    <body>
    <h:form>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2">   
                <h:commandButton id="submit" action="#{pageServiceBean.submit}" value="#{msgs.save}" />     
            <h:commandButton id="cancel" action="#{pageServiceBean.cancel}" value="#{msgs.cancel}" immediate="true"/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <div style="background-color:navy;width:100%;color:white"></div>
    </h:form>

</body>
</html>
```

**store.xhtml**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"> 

    <ui:composition template="META-INF/templates/AdvanceTemplate.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
         <h:form>    
             <h:panelGrid columns="2"> 




                      <h:outputText value="#{msgs.hostname}"></h:outputText>
                      <h:inputText id="idName" value="#{pageServiceBean.newData.name}"                      
                      </h:inputText>
                      <h:outputText value="#{msgs.type}"></h:outputText>
                      <h:inputText value="#{pageServiceBean.newData.type}"></h:inputText>                                



               </h:panelGrid> 

            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
    </html>
```

Comment: why you need the button in the footer? The right place for the button is in the form that you want to submit.

Comment: i want to create the input-field dynamic with java script. And think it would be a good idea to place the static elements like the button outside (like footer and header).

Answer (score 0):

Use `<f:ajax/>` in between `<h:inputText>` tag.

```
<h:inputText id="idName" value="#{pageServiceBean.newData.name}">
    <f:ajax/>      
</h:inputText>
```

Note: I have not tested your code sample.